# Dell 5570 and SSD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I have a Dell 5570 with a Toshiba MQ01ACF050 HDD. I want to install an additional SSD. The guy from service said it's possible when I was buying it.

M.2 SSD with HDD removed:

[image: M.2 SSD with HDD removed]

HDD on board:

[image: HDD on board]

What options do I have?

1. I can try to take off this black wrapping from HDD and put the M.2 SSD on top of HDD, though I don't think there will be enough space and it is a good idea in general.
2. I can buy another SSD and put it in WWAN (you can see it in the first picture). What form factor do I have to buy?
3. It seems I can replace my HDD with this M.2 SSD I have, but I need this [bracket](http://www.dell.com/support/article/rs/ru/rsbsdt1/sln300895/dell-lat-e5270-e5470-e5570-and-precision-3510-m2-pcie-upgrade-requirements?lang=en), right?
4. I can buy a standard 2.5" SSD and replace my HDD with it.

Does the second option only allow me to have two disks? Will there be issue with boot sector on disk placed in WWAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to install both HDD and M.2 2280. 
I installed M.2 2242 in WWAN. It is detected with system.

Answer (score 1):

"Put M2 on top of hard drive": No. You remove the hard drive as you have done, then you connect the m2, then you put the HDD back in.

The connector for the m2 is marked "M2x3" in your photo. Use the retention screw to secure it, and then put the HDD back in.

[The manual (page14)](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/latitude-e5570-laptop_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf)

Comment: How can I put HDD back when M2 will be in? I can't insert M2 when HDD is already here because it has same level as higher HDD part.  There won't be enough place to put HDD back. And I can't secure it with retention screw. I have to use bracket from 3 "my option". And it will steal HDD space.

Comment: @coul, I am currently about to try this. Were you able to install the M2 next to the HDD or did you have to go to the WWAN alternative?